# Why the Partial input basic type returns itself

Tags: typescript

Partial source code:

```
type Partial<T> = { [P in keyof T]?: T[P]; }
```

I want to know why the Partial input basic type（Like string return string） returns itself instead of an error or an object.

```
// undef => undefined

type undef = Partial<undefined>;

// str => string

type str = Partial<string>;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just the intended behavior of TS. Technically everything in JS is an object, including string and more, etc.

So when you do something like Partial, TS doesn't throw an error because strings are a type of object. It just so happens when you make all the keys optional it does not really do anything

```js
string extends Object ? true : false //=> this is true
```

To prevent this behavior, or if you want a more strict version of Partial, you should instead use something like extends Record<any, any>

```js
string extends Record<any, any> ? true : false //=> false

//Thus we can rewrite our Partial function
type PartialStrict<T extends Record<any, any>> = Partial<T>

type test2 = PartialStrict<string> //Error! Type 'string' does not satisfy the constraint 'Record<any, any>'.
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBMEM7AAxQLxQQJwJYDsDmUEAHrDgCZxQDyARgFYQDGwUA-DBgK7QBcUAZgEMANnAgAoAPSSoUAHqtxoSDHjAAjKnTBs+QiQjlKAJSYB7DGQA8gnCAA0UWyAB8bDtyh8hoidNkK4krg0AAKghjAWCIAyjpYzFYAKvqkFFCmjBbWzo7OLm5o4ZHRwskuQcrQsAgATFrFUbHxiZi4eBVAA)